# iOS In App Purchases restore transaction not working properly with Milkman Games ANE for Adobe AIR

Tags: ios, air, adobe, in-app-purchase

I am experiencing the following problems with Milkman Games in-app-purchases ANE dor Adobe AIR:

**PROBLEM 1**

1. StoreKit is created and correctly returns all the product IDs via
   StoreKit.storeKit.loadProductDetails()
2. I purchase item A, the item is correctly purchased
3. I purchase item B, the item is correctly purchased
4. I uninstall and re-install the app
5. I restore transactions via StoreKit.storeKit.restoreTransactions()
6. Only item B is restored ( onPurchaseSuccess() is only triggered once
   for item B)

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR**:

I would expect that restoreTransactions() would trigger onPurchaseSuccess() for each of the items previously restored.

**PROBLEM 2**

6. I close the app
7. When I restart the app, onPurchaseSuccess() for product B is fired without any of the app code calling it.

Is StoreKit attempting to restore transactions by default everytime StoreKit is created? (i.e. StoreKit.create(); )

```
Testing device: iPad2, iPhone4
Operating System: iOS 7 and iOS 6
Compiling for: AIR 3.8
IDE: FlashDevelop
```

*Type of item purchased:* all items tested are non-consumable

Did anyone ever experienced such a behaviour with iOS in-app-purchases in an AIR mobile app? Any ideas or pointer in the right direction are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Isn't the IAP ANE a paid product with support?  From the milkman website, http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/contact-us/ `For technical support, get in touch at support@milkmangames.com`

Comment: That's correct Jeff, I also contacted Milkman Games for customer support, but in the meantime I was wondering if someone else was experiencing the same problems. Apparently so, because they just got back to me with a product update released today. The updated version (v. 2.0.1) solved the problems I described above.

Answer (score 0):

An updated version (v. 2.0.1) of this ANE released today by Milkman Games solved the problems I described above.